# Chefspec and stubbing shell_out commands

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chefspec

I've written a library method in my cookbook which would read the /etc/fstab file and modify it if there are certain options missing for mounts.

When I try to write Chefspec tests, they all fail to returns the stubbed information, but rather read the local /etc/fstab on my computer.

I'm wondering what would be the correct syntax to stub a sample fstab which I expect on production servers and pass that information to the library method when running Chefspec.

The library method is in libraries/fstab_quota.rb file:

```
    module ApplicationQuota
      module Fstab
        def read_fstab
          cmd = shell_out('cat /etc/fstab')
          cmd.run_command

          cmd.stdout.split("\n").each do |fs|
            # Logic here
          end
      end
    end
[Chef::Recipe, Chef::Resource].each  do |l|
  l.send :include, ::ApplicationQuota::Fstab
end
```

I'd then call the library method inside the cookbook recipe:

```
# Fstab returns either an Array if there are modifications or false if 
# no modifications have been made
fstab = read_fstab

file '/etc/fstab' do
  content fstab.join("\n")
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "644"
  action :create
  only_if { fstab }
end
```

Comment: I think this library should be covered with conventional rspec and not with ChefSpec. In ChefSpec you would stub `read_fstab` with something like `allow(Chef::Recipe).to receive('read_fstab').and_return(['stubbed','array','values','for','this','test'])`

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to the right path, using  `Chef::Recipe.any_instance.stub(:read_fstab).and_return([...])`

Comment: The recommended syntax is `allow_any_instance_of(Chef::Recipe).to receive` instead of stub. I though `allow` would be enought, my bad.

Comment: Exactly, that worked perfectly and Rubocop checks passed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stub the shell_out command itself.

```
my_double = double('shellout_double')
allow(my_double).to receive(:run_command)
allow(my_double).to receive(:stdout).and_return(.....)
allow(Mixlib:ShellOut).to receive(:shell_out).with("your command").and_return(my_double)
```